# Checkpoint SSL network extender is unsecured

Tags: ssl, vpn, remote-access, firewall, checkpoint

I am currently exploring Checkpoint SSL network extender, and I found that it only supports AES, 3DES, RC4 ciphers algorithms, and these are weaker and more vulnerable cipher.

Does this means the network extender is unsecured? I have done some searching on Internet and it seems like no one is discussing about the insecure ciphers algorithms being used.

I think it should support more recent cipher like AES256, or I am wrong?

Appreciate any insight provided.